# Trying to Access Enclosure

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rss

I'm trying to access an RSS enclosure from jQuery and the jGFeed plugin.  Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.jGFeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/solidverbal', function(feeds){
        // Check for errors
        if(!feeds){
        // there was an error
        return false;
        }
        // do whatever you want with feeds here
        var t = "";
        for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
            var entry = feeds.entries[i];
            // Entry title
            console.log(entry);
            t = t + "<li><a href='"  + entry.mediaGroups + "'>" + entry.title + "</a><br/>" + entry.content + "</li>";
        }
        $("#results").html("<ul>" + t + "</ul>");

    }, 10);
});
</script>
```

How do I access this?  When it's converted to JSON, the enclosure shows up in a "mediaGroups" object?  Can someone help me access these URLs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can send the `feeds` JSON to another function for manipulation:

```
        if(!feeds){
          // there was an error
          return false;
        }
        // do whatever you want with feeds here
        feedsFunction(feeds);
        var t = "";
        for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
            var entry = feeds.entries[i];
            // Entry title
            console.log(entry);
            t = t + "<li><a href='"  + entry.mediaGroups + "'>" + entry.title + "</a><br/>" + entry.content + "</li>";
        }
        $("#results").html("<ul>" + t + "</ul>");
```

Comment: Hi Neal -- Thanks for the reply.  Is there an example I can find of a function that could manipulate a feed?  Somewhat new to this, just looking for examples to help get my feet wet.

Comment: I want to access the URL of the enclosure.

Comment: lol i have no idea what is in that JSON. u can fig out how to manipulate it lol